# Get All Values, by Key, In a List of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, dictionary

I have a list of Dictionaries, like so: `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object?>>`

I would like to get all values (object) from said list of dictionary, where Key = "Language"

How can I do this using LinQ, without iterating through all of my list?

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: That data construct seems wrong. Why not use a LookUp instead of Dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid a double lookup using `TryGetValue`

```cs
var result = list
    .Select(dict => dict.TryGetValue("Language", out var lang) ? lang : null)
    .Where(val => val != null);
```

Comment: Nice... This makes me remove my own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) to flatten the lists:

```
var result = obj.SelectMany(c => c
                      .Where(dict => dict.Key == "Language"))
                      .Select(dict => dict.Value);
```

Do note @Charlieface answer is better because it makes use of the dictionaries optimized lookup functionality - avoiding one loop.

Comment: I was not the one giving a downvote, but the reason for it is presumably that your code does not compile. Seeing as `obj` is an `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object?>>`, you are currently trying to get the `Key` value of an `object`, not of a `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the select and where. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 
   list.Select(dict => dict.ContainsKey( "Language" ) ? dict[ "Language" ] : null )
       .Where( val => val != null );
```

Comment: There is also the option of first filtering, and then selecting the appropriate value. That way, you don't need to filter out `null` values: `list.Where(dict => dict.ContainsKey(...)).Select(dict => dict[...]);`